# Android and OpenID support using Spring Security

Tags: java, android, rest, spring-security, openid

I am trying to authenticate my user from my Android application to my server using *Spring Security OpenID*, to call webservices (secured by Spring Security).

I looked `AccountManager` from Android to get google account (I obtain email address).

So, how to authenticate using OpenID (I cannot post `j_spring_openid_security_check` because user action is needed to authorize access, and is a webpage...) ?

or How to secure my REST Webservices call (if OpenID authentication is not possible) ?